# The expression isn't shown entirely

Tags: amsmath

I am writing a text in LATEX and I wrote this:

```
\begin{align*} 
\epsilon_p(a+b)&=((a+b)\pmod p, (a+b)\pmod{p^2}, (a+b)\pmod{p^3}, \dots )\\ 
&=(a\pmod p+b\pmod p, a\pmod{p^2}+b\pmod{p^2}, a\pmod{p^3}+ b \pmod{p^3}, \dots) \\ 
&=(a\pmod p, a\pmod{p^2},a\pmod{p^3}, \dots)+(b\pmod p, b\pmod{p^2}, b\pmod{p^3}, \dots) \\ 
&=\epsilon_p(a)+\epsilon_p(b) 
\end{align*}
```

but the expression is cut off and isn't shown entirely... Why does this happen? :( What could I do?

PS: I started as follows:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \begin{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example, not a puzzle or a MWE construction kit ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`\pmod` is not intended to use as an infix expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\epsilon_p(a+b)&=((a+b)\bmod p, (a+b)\bmod{p^2}, (a+b)\bmod{p^3}, \dots )\\
&=(a\bmod p+b\bmod p, a\bmod{p^2}\\
& \qquad + b\bmod{p^2}, a\bmod{p^3}+ b \bmod{p^3}, \dots) \\
&=(a\bmod p, a\bmod{p^2},a\bmod{p^3}, \dots)\\
&\qquad +(b\bmod p, b\bmod{p^2}, b\bmod{p^3}, \dots) \\
&=\epsilon_p(a)+\epsilon_p(b)
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

note that this required `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\epsilon_p(a+b)&=((a+b)\bmod p, (a+b)\bmod{p^2}, (a+b)\bmod{p^3}, \dots )\\
&= \begin{multlined}[t]
  (a\bmod p+b\bmod p,\\
   a\bmod{p^2}+b\bmod{p^2}, a\bmod{p^3}+ b \bmod{p^3}, \dots)
 \end{multlined} \\
&= \begin{multlined}[t]
  (a\bmod p, a\bmod{p^2},a\bmod{p^3}, \dots)\\
  +(b\bmod p, b\bmod{p^2}, b\bmod{p^3}, \dots)
  \end{multlined} \\
&=\epsilon_p(a)+\epsilon_p(b)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]